# Laravel Sail MSSQL database creation on startup

Tags: sql-server, laravel, odbc, laravel-sail

I am currently working on Laravel Sail in combination with SQL server. What i want to do is create databases on sail startup but i can't seem to figure out how to edit my Dockerfile in a way that i can login to the sql server and create the databases. This is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis \
       php-pear \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools \
    && ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd /usr/bin/sqlcmd \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \
       gcc \
       musl-dev \
       make \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv

RUN printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
RUN printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
RUN phpenmod sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

I seen some posts on creating an entrypoint.sh and starting the sql server simultaneously but i can't seem to figure out on how to make that work with my Dockerfile, can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: is the SQL server in a container or on the host?

Comment: There are two containers, one for php running the app and one separate for mssql

Comment: Any code that initialises the database should be in `start-container` (if you can modify that file) and you should make sure that in your docker-compose.yml you specify that your `web` container depends on your mssql container